# Show if a person is editing a post

Tags: feature-request, posts

Often, I see an incomplete post getting quickly down-voted; then, the author edits it, making it fine, but the down-voter never revokes it.

Should we add a system where you can see if someone is currently editing, and maybe see their edits live, like Google Docs for example? This way, people can know when to hold off on voting and see what the edit is.

Comment: This would be a very useful feature to implement, I think. There must be some way to prevent edit conflicts when multiple users are editing a question at the same time.

Comment: @AndersonGreen From what I understand of the question, this isn't a suggestion to add an edit conflict resolution system (where there's already one, albeit a simple one); it's a request to add an indicator when answers are in the process of being edited, for when someone posts a short answer and then edits it later.

Comment: @Nightfirecat I did mean that as well, with a live update system

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177930/first-draft-bad-question-flags

Comment: Also related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98022/how-soon-should-i-vote-to-close

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have plenty of time to write a good question/answer. You can't expect people to wait for you to release the last edit before voting on your answer/question. Either you write it good the first time and adjust few things later on or you'll get down voted and hope that people will take a look at recent edits after a while.

Comment: I agree. FGITW isn't a problem anymore due to randomization of answer order, so there should be no need to worry about posting your answer as soon as possible.

Comment: +1: The OP is given an infinite amount of time to post the question initially and there are even a clear set of guidelines before they post.

Comment: @Nightfirecat Perhaps it depends on the tag, but for a lot of jQuery and JavaScript questions that's simply not true. Getting a quick answer out first will start getting you votes, pushing your answer to the top of the list, then you can edit in more detail afterwards. There's still a definite incentive to posting an answer quickly, though that's definitely not the case for a question.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist If it's a question that doesn't need a long, detailed answer, one shouldn't need overmuch time to consider their post. Quality doesn't always mean having the longest post.

Comment: @Nightfirecat I agree, but these are questions that (in my opinion, at least) need detailed answers (by which I mean something more than just a code solution). What I'm seeing in practice in those tags is completely contrary to what you said in your initial comment; FGITW is a problem (of sorts) and people are worriying about posting their answer as quickly as possible. People are posting one or two lines quickly to get votes from the initial interest in the question - putting them ahead of the crowd - and then gradually editing their answer into the one they know it should actually be.

Answer (score 2):

There is already a system that informs the users who are watching a question when the question or one of the answers have been edited, or when a new answer is added. Clearly, that happens when the edit is complete, not when the post is being edited, but if a user doesn't down-vote and immediately runs off to a different question, he should notice the post has been edited.

Considering the reasons why a down-vote is normally casted, I take that the down-voted post is so bad that, for the vote to be removed, it would require rewriting at least a sentence. I would suppose that the down-vote is not given because you wrote `isnull()` instead of `is_null()` in an answer about PHP code.

I don't think the requested feature is going to help with the down-voters; there would be probably users who down-vote you because what you wrote, independently from the fact you are going to edit your post.