# Should there be a delay for close votes?

Tags: discussion, questions, vote-to-close, question-quality

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417732/please-help-to-understand-asp-net) was closed only five minutes after it was asked. Sure this was not a good quality question.

But there was not a real chance to put comments on it, the asker had not even a chance to fix his question.

So shouldn't there be a delay (say one hour) until the question can be closed?

Comment: +1 Yes, I agree with you, there should be a time limit before closing the new question. Sometimes new users are not aware of question rules and when their question gets closed, they think site is not useful and left the site forever.

Comment: @Downvoter: care to comment?

Comment: See the section on voting, it might explain the downvotes: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta That said, a question being put on hold/closed does not mean the question is dead. The OP still has all the time in the world to address the issues.

Comment: I've seen questions closing in 50 seconds

Comment: Apparently the intention is that these questions are actually "on hold" pending improvement.  However, this is not at all obvious, A new user who gets their question "closed" within minutes will never come back.

Comment: Related: [How soon should I vote to close?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98022/165773) and [Can we be a bit quicker to close (downvote) questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203830/165773)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no need for a delay; that's just delaying the inevitable.

Suppose there *was* a delay; the OP wouldn't know there was a problem until an extra hour later.

More to the point, with [the recent changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons) to question closing, the first 5 days of a question being closed shows the question as "on hold", not closed.

The specific close reason chosen gives a detailed description of the problem, so the OP can improve their question.

In the case of the specific question you linked to, it's a prime example of a good question to close. It shows no effort to solve the problem, shows no code that's been tried, is extremely vague and unclear, and basically says "give me c0dez".

Also, when a question is closed, it isn't closed forever. There is always the opportunity to reopen it. Furthermore, after a question is closed, if the OP edits it, it automatically enters the Reopen review queue as a candidate to reopen.

Overall, I don't see any point in adding a delay.

Comment: I was not aware that the OP can still fix his question if it is [on hold].