# downvoting something that can be changed or has been changed

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I get that it's important to deliver readable code for users who take their time to actually help you with something, but do you think this should be a reason to downvote a question that can be changed ? Especially for users who are new to coding and are not quite proficient at it ?

How about only downvoting the question itself, since it is an unchangeable aspect of itself ?

I don't feel attacked by just being downvoted or anything but the point is, that a question which is downvoted for something that can be changed or has been changed is probably not going to get many views yet the matter of the question remains the same...

Comment: You cannot assume a post was downvoted just because it was formatted incorrectly, however (which is what I assume you mean by *can be changed*).

Comment: Not sure what you are saying. Are you suggesting we should not downvote questions if the only problem is formatting?

Comment: the thing is: i have no idea why it was downvoted and the only complain was the formating, so how can i avoid being downvoted in the future when i have no idea why it happened ?

Comment: related (probably not a duplicate): [How soon should I “vote to close”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98022/how-soon-should-i-vote-to-close)

Comment: well the question was specific (at least in my opinion) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26234958/after-numberformatexception-is-caught-the-do-something-block-is-still-executed

Answer (score 0):

> How about only downvoting the question itself, since it is an unchangeable aspect of itself ?

I don't think this is feasible at all.

Let's say the question was somehow separated from the code, and you could only vote on the question. That doesn't remove the fact that the code is an integral part of the question. What if a question doesn't contain any code at all? I, along with everybody else, would still be voting on the question based on it's code (or lack thereof).

I think the problem is that it wasn't clear to you that the comments weren't related to the downvotes until the question was closed. I can't say that there's really a fix for that either.

In short, your question was downvoted and closed for not actually asking a question. It would have been helpful if someone had asked you what you were trying to ask in the comments, but that's not something that's required, nor should it be. Now that your question is closed you can see the reason, and what you need to fix in order to re-open it.

Comment: i fully understand that, but i'd like to know why something is downvoted in order to avoid it in the future, downvoting without saying why is quite useless since there is no way of improving

Comment: @SklogW Unfortunately that's another debate that's been going on for quite a while now. It's not really useful to force comments from people, because people who don't want to comments aren't going to leave useful comments. Until someone figures out a better solution, we have suggestions to leave comments to leave comments when downvoting: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes

Comment: @SklogW: If it's non-obvious to you what might be causing downvotes on your post, there's no harm in asking. I have seen people add comments like "I would be happy to improve my answer, if someone could just point out why it is being downvoted." Or, even ask on the meta site where your posts for people to have a look and offer you pointers to improve your posts. (Do be wary of the "meta effect", though.)

Comment: One pointer I'll offer: you tend to use non-standard English. The first-person pronoun "I" is _always_ capitalized, as is the first letter of a sentence.