# Provide a button on pressing which post a question automatically after 40 minutes

Tags: feature-request, questions

When one with a low number of reputation points tries to post two questions within 40 minutes they receive the message it's about 'allowing to post a question once every 40 minutes' rule.

I would like to propose a feature of delayed posting. It may be on a button labelled with "Automatically post after 40 minutes" in which if you click your question will automatically be posted after 40 minutes. Or may be just when you ask a question within 40 minutes automatically system will provide you a message that the question will be posted after 40 minutes of your previous question and the system will automatically post it.

Comment: when posting, asker would better be around and watching for requests to clarify because if it turns out that something in it needs to be clarified [readers won't be willing to wait before closing it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98026/165773)

Comment: As gnat, it's always a good idea to stick around for (at least) a few minutes after posting the question. Otherwise, if potential answerers need to ask you something in the comments and you're not there for a while, you risk having the question closed and/or downvoted. People tend to [downvote for unresponsiveness](https://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive).

Comment: People can, of course, automate posting questions if they choose. Providing such automation as a normal part of the user interface noticeably reduces the effectiveness of such rate limiting, along with being counter to at least some of the reasons behind having such rate limits.

Answer (score 18):

That rather defeats the purpose of *rate limiting* when you're essentially turning a rate limit into a queue. We *want* people to stop and think about the question(s) they're posting, rather than overenthusiastically asking a bunch of poorly recieved questions, then getting downvoted/closed, and generally having a bad experience as a user.

If folks weren't to wait, there would be no ratelimit, rather than an option that essentially nerfs it.

Comment: downvoted/closed and subsequently rate limited to once per 6 months due to their post being of low quality.

Answer (score 7):

In the rather rare case that a user (with less than 125 reputation, see the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900/295232)) has written two well-researched high quality questions within 40 minutes, I would advise them to start a timer (on their computer, phone or an old-fashioned egg timer) or set a reminder somewhere. Stack Exchange sites save posts you write as drafts, so you won't lose them when the browser window closes. You can even start writing the question on your computer and submit it via your phone (like I did with this answer).

Comment: Oh you show off ;)