# Does placing On Hold sooner rather than later improve chances of highly upvoted answers?

Tags: discussion, on-hold

On a per-site Meta I have been asked in a [comment](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4688/how-to-best-suggest-more-responsible-forum-moderation/4689?noredirect=1#comment8640_4689):

> The key assumption here is that putting questions on hold motivates
>   people to improve them in a way that friendlier measures like comments
>   and requests for clarification can not. Is there any evidence for
>   this?

As soon as I think a question needs improvement to meet our quality standards and that its asker might not respond to those "friendlier measures" quickly I try to [Always vote to close immediately](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98026/215590).  I usually perform those "friendlier measures" at the same time in case I have misjudged.

Consequently, answers like these resonate with me:

- [Always vote to close immediately](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98026/215590)
- [noise reduction](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10894/215590)
- [preventing other users from answering is exactly why we close questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92638/215590)

However, I cannot recall seeing any data to confirm or refute what I think is common sense above.

Is there any data, perhaps from SEDE, that shows whether questions that end up being placed On Hold at some point, are more likely to receive highly upvoted ( = high quality) answers by being placed On Hold sooner rather than later?

Defining "highly upvoted" may be difficult so perhaps any such analysis should use at least three values to counter any claim that it has placed the bar too high.

Comment: It keeps people from answering questions they shouldn't, until they reach a state they should. To me, that's totally the reason I rather close quickly, to get rid of broken windows until they are fixed...

Comment: Just speculation (and thus not an answer), but consider placing a question on hold within minutes instead of hours: You're more likely to actually reach the OP, and they're more likely to be in a place to fix the question (rather than forget about it). Does that actually happen, and how often? Don't know.

Comment: What Journeyman Geek said. It isn't about encouraging higher-quality answers; it's about *preventing low-quality answers* that will be irrelevant once the question is edited and improved. The data you're seeking here is irrelevant.

Comment: @CodyGray I get what you and JourneymanGeek are saying - it's a better way of explaining my gut feeling that voting On Hold sooner rather than later is the way to go - I would be happy to accept an answer along those lines.

Comment: That's not something for a SEDE-query but for an AI analysis since you'd need to consider the quality of the editing, the time of closing and re-opening, possibly the editor and certainly the general quality of the question after re-opening as well as the general quality of the answers of the answerer who gives the high-quality answer, and of course you'd need to qualify good answers and all those things deviate between sites, possibly topics on sites and probably a dozen factors I didn't think of.

Comment: @Helmar an answer outlining the difficulty of providing an answer is itself a valuable answer.

Comment: I think line @Helmar for the analysis, as its complex, as like the time you took to close the question, an user migh find time to write a good answer on another question because he didnt did moderation task before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if it does.

That said, the *primary* reason a poor question should be put on hold immediately, is simply because there's no value in keeping it in its current form, and some people might chose to answer it, either speculatively, or because they don't know better.

If a question can be fixed, it ought to be. I *try* to leave a comment to let a user know why a question is put on hold, but in many cases, the aim is education for the *next* time.

As such - if a closed question has *fundamental* quality issues, its unlikely to have highly upvotable answers unless the fixes made are excellent, or you have the rare case of there being well recieved answers *on their own merit*. Neither of these would, to me, have anything to do with time to close.

Comment: If the idea is to encourage the question to be improved, editing would be better than putting on hold.

Comment: @ゼーロ that would improve the question rather than encourage the question to be improved.  A large part of SE's scalability is that editing is performed by as many users as possible but most of all by its question askers.  I was alerted to the need to learn how to edit the first time a question of mine went On Hold and I realized that only by editing to improve it would it get any answers.

Comment: I'm just trying to make the site less hostile to new users. Guidance rather than sanction. It seems that a lot of users affected by this don't know what they need to do to fix it.

Comment: @ゼーロ A moderator assisted me to understand the SE philosophy not long after I started using SE sites when he said that it is "carrot and stick".  Just giving guidance does not always result in question improvement when the asker is receiving answers anyway.  Sometimes it is only when access to answers without improvement that questions improve (and improve quickly).

Comment: @PolyGeo seems like he meant he was hitting people with the stick... Carrot and stick would be leading the user to a better question, not trying to place it on hold as quickly as possible.

Comment: @ゼーロ He used a lot of carrot and not much stick, and I think burned out as a result i.e. helped some users fantastically for a few years and nowadays seems to rarely answer.

Comment: @PolyGeo hah, Also, don't forget various day jobs. Being a mod dosen't pay the bills. If I have less time and energy to answer stuff, its as much real life as anything.  If I'm hitting a *bunch* of answers at once, it means I have time on my hands more than anything else.  Not really burnt out - just that the tooling makes hands on commenting less needed, when there's already comments off the review queue and such.